# How do I grant permissions for a SQL Server Management Studio user to access system.views in an Azure Managed Instance?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am connecting to an Azure SQL managed instance with Active Directory through SQL Server Management Studio.

I'm trying to access system views, like:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_details
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys
```

I get the following error message in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
The module being executed is not trusted. Either the owner of the database of the module needs to be granted authenticate permission, or the module needs to be digitally signed.
```

SELECT CURRENT_USER says that I am logged in as "dbo".

These views work for an on-premises SQL server, so it must be an Azure Managed Instance issue.

How do I grant the SSMS user (dbo) the appropriate permissions to access system views?

Comment: What permissions does the login have on-premise vs. the managed instance, specifically, is the login a member of sysadmin on either, or been granted VIEW SERVER STATE on either?